# Ofbiz want to import data from accounting software to ofbiz

Tags: erp, accounting, ofbiz

I want to import an accounting software data in ofbiz. Can any one suggest me how to do this and is there any reference available to understand ofbiz accounting flow.

Answer (score 1):

I am new with OFBiz too , but i like to share my point of view with you.as i understand .

if you need to Import accounting data in ofbiz . you can change the entityenging.xml file and import the ofbiz data to any database. ofbiz support many databases like oracle,mysql,derby ,etc and you can extract any data you need to from it. its the fast way and u can keep up with real-time data. u can use any reporting tool or BI analyzing tool as you like with it.

for more information use this
          https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/How+to+migrate+OfBiz+from+Derby+to+MySQL+database

i have using with it with oracle.

you can also export a table data to XML file.

with webtools >> import/export

If  u need help to understand the flow of accounting , the best way is use it and learn with database and track the xml files of it but its hard (i am also trying to get how commission run works).but you can use

```
http://docs.huihoo.com/apache/ofbiz/OFBiz-An-Insider-View.pdf
```

or

https://www.scribd.com/doc/138056993/Accounting-5-Step-Guide

for a little help i think !!

Hope this helps you!! good luck !!